# Visual Studio Shell 2015 does not use custom icons in solution explorer

Tags: c#, vix, visual-studio-shell

I have upgraded my application from VS Shell 2013 to Shell 2015 and the custom icons for my editor extensions are not visible in the solution explorer. During the upgrade the wix is also upgraded to 3.10

The icons are installed with Wix through the deployment, the registry entries are created correctly and the file explorer shows the custom icons for the extension.

When I add for example a *.docx then it has a proper icon in the solution explorer only with my custom icons have an issue. Do You have any idea what goes wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have found a problem, but I still don't understand. The custom icons are in the C:\Program Files (x86)\My Application folder and in the regedit the Value data of the .xyz extension is "C:\Program Files (x86)\My Application\Icon.ico". When I remove the apostrophes then it is working in the solution explorer.

It is installed with WIX with the following way:

```
<File Id="IconFile" Name='Icon.ico' DiskId='1' Source='$(var.BuildOutputDir)\Icon.ico' KeyPath='yes' />
<ProgId Id="CustomFile" Icon="IconFile">
    <Extension Id="xyz" ContentType="application/text"></Extension>
</ProgId>
```

As I know the apostrophes are mandatory due the spaces in the path. Is it true? Can I force somehow WIX to not use the apostrophes?

Or the error is in the shell to find the icon in this format, because it is working with the Shell 13

Comment: Hi, if you want to add additional information to your question you should edit the question, instead of posting an answer (which will probalby lead to downvotes).